# HttpURLConnections works on PC but not on Android

Tags: java, android, html, httpurlconnection

The following code works just fine on my PC and the server returns `200 Ok` as well as the correct output. When I try it on Android, the server retruns:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /sg-1/locations/. Reason:
<pre>    Method Not Allowed</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/></html>
```

Code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
    // connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("X-Session", token);

    connection.connect();
    InputStream response;
    boolean worked = false;
    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        response = connection.getErrorStream();
    else {
        response = connection.getInputStream();
        worked = true;
    }
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(response).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sends `GET` in Java SE and `POST` in Android. It seems that the server is expecting a `GET` request, so prevent sending `POST` in Android by removing this line:

```java
// connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Comment: That does not seem to be the solution, I removed the line from my code, the symptoms are still exactly the same.

Comment: @Grunzwanzling do you have control over the server? it is important to know what HTTP method the server expects and set it explicitly e.g. `connection.setRequestMethod("GET");`. I presumed it was `GET`

Comment: No, it is a public (inofficial) API, so I can't even ask the developer. I will try your solution tomorrow anyways.